# Asking the user if they want to try to play again

Tags: python, loops, user-input

So basically I'm creating a pretty basic guessing game that asks the user to enter a number from 1 to 15

```
##My Code
import sys
import random
number = random.randint(1, 15)

def guessGame():
 tries = 1
 while tries <= 1:
  tries = tries + 1

try:
 guess = input("What is your guess? ")
 guess_int = int(guess)

except ValueError:
  print("This is not a number")
  sys.exit()
  
else:  
 if guess_int > 15:
  print("The number you entered is greater than 15")
  print("The game’s guess is:", number)
 elif guess_int < number:
   print("Your guess is smaller than the game’s guess")
   print("The game’s guess is:", number)
 elif guess_int > number:
   print("Your guess is greater than the game’s guess")
   print("The game’s guess is:", number)
 elif guess_int == number:
   print("Congratulations, you've guessed correctly!")
   print("The game’s guess is:", number)

tryagain = str(input("Play again? yes or no "))
if tryagain == "yes": 
    print("Let’s play again! ")
    guessGame()
elif tryagain == "no":
   print("GAME OVER")
```

Now my program runs fine but I can't seem to get the part where the user enters yes to play again to actually work, for some reason nothing happens even though am calling the function to start looping again

Comment: The indentation is completely off. This is not valid code. Please fix the indentation, and use more than just one space for indenting (4 spaces is advised)

Comment: I guess this occurred while trying to copy and paste from the file to the website, will fix it on a bit !

Comment: You've put everything in a function (or at least you probably did, your .. creative indentation makes it hard to see) and currently it's not at all doing what I think you intended it to do. The default indent for Python is 4 spaces. If you use a decent editor or IDE, that will be the default as well and you would do well to use it. Regardless, you never call your function `guessGame()`, so the game never starts. Also, you can restart the game by calling the function again and again, but ultimately that could exceed recursion depth and wastes a few resources every time - have a look at `while`